# .htaccess redirect loop error

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I created a .htaccess with the following goals:

**1: Remove .php and force add trailing slash**

**2: Make http://website.com/sticker/fruit/apple = sticker.php?category=fruit&alt=apple**

That works, but whenever I type something that does not exist, for example:

http://website.com/sdgsdg/ OR
http://website.com/dssdg/sdgsg/zkzzv/

I get redirect errors.

Here is my .htacess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php/$ http://website.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ http://website.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://website.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sticker/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ sticker.php?category=$1&alt=$2 [NC,L]
```

Can anyone spot whats causing the redirect loops?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: your rules work fine for me

Comment: Yeah, they worked fine for me on localhost. Once I published the website, I got loads of redirect errors.

Comment: What does your access logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sticker/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$ sticker.php?category=$1&alt=$2 [NC,L]
```